# Access windows service / WCF service from other machine on LAN

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, windows-services, lan

Please bear with me as I am beginner to Windows service / WCF service. After much research I have not been able to find satisfactory solution to my problem. Let me describe my problem in brief:

I want to run one Windows service / WCF service on a machine on LAN. I want to make that service to be consumed by applications running on another machines on the LAN, provided following conditions must be satisfied :

1) I should not need to host Windows service / WCF service to IIS.

2) The URL of service should be configurable in the applications running on other machines on LAN. I should not have to hard code the URL anywhere in those applications (e.g. in App.config or so). Service URL should be accepted from the application user. At the best, the application should find the machine on which the service is running and should call the service from there. 
(As a side note, the applications running on other machines are in-browser Silverlight applications.)

Is it a tall order? If not, which of the Windows service and WCF service will suit my requirements? Please provide me any resource if you have.

Comment: 1. Windows Services and WCF services are two separate items.  A WCF service can be hosted in a Windows Service.  This is a separate hosting option from hosting it in IIS.  2.  It's not entirely clear what (or why) you're trying to do, but take a look at [WCF Discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456782%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Its definitely not a tall order. I am not sure why you are confused between windows service and WCF. Based on your problem statement, i think WCF service is the one you need to create. You can host it outside IIS as self hosting managed application. You can also host it as a Windows service. Check the details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158(v=vs.110).aspx)